# How do I get the same CLI tools in a {{Powershell::Powershell as Admin}} tab as in a {{cmd::Cmder as Admin}} tab in Cmder?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmder

I recently installed Cmder and I've been using the {{cmd::Cmder as Admin}} task for my tabs because it comes with a lot of nice bash-isms that I find missing in PowerShell. E.g. `touch`, `du`, `ssh`, `head`, `tail`.

However, I'm aware that PowerShell is the modern choice and is a lot more powerful than plain cmd for Windows-centric tasks. However, I lament not being able to use the bash commands I'm familiar with. Is there a way to get the Cmder tools  in my Cmder PowerShell tabs?

Comment: Mixing PowerShell and non-PS tools is probably a poor idea, especially since PS directly aliases some *nix commands (with different arguments, mind!). I would suggest that you try to recreate the specific commands you need via custom functions in your PowerShell profile, if possible, and [alias the rest](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/06/10/exe-alias-in-powershell.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oops... sorry, I answered the wrong question. I'm going to leave it anyway because I think it is relevent]

Coming from years of use of Cygwin Zsh as my primary shell, I faced the same transition issue. There are at least a couple of approaches.

The one I took was to simply bite the bullet and commit myself fully to Powershell. The first thing I did was create a tiny script which removes all the DOS & bash "transition" aliases to keep myself from cheating. Then I added a call to this script in my profile.

After that it was just a matter of incrementally learning idiomatic powershell habits to replace my old idiomatic zsh habits. I haven't found anything that I can't do, though sometimes the ps idioms are a bit bulkier than I'd wish.

The other approach is to install either Cygwin (my preference) or UnxUtils. Either of these have exact syntactic equivalents of almost all the gnu utilities ***which can be invoked directly from the powershell command line (or a ps script).***

Still, my recommendation... force yourself to learn the powershell equivalents